# why 0 < string.size() - N is true, while string.size() = 0

Tags: c++, string

I am setting up a bool expression to entry loop; but the bool expression return a wrong answer?

```cpp
s = "";
bool flag_1 = (0 < (s.size() - 10));

int temp = s.size() - 10;
bool flag_2 = 0 < temp; 

//flag_2 and flag_1 should be the same,but they are different.
```

Comment: Hint: `s.size()` doesn't return an `int`.

Comment: `s.size()` returns a `size_t` which is defined as an unsigned type. Substracting a positive value from an unsigned type would always result in a positive number. Be sure to enable all compiler warnings, this should have been told so then.

Comment: Could you please explain more detail? why when i use a temp variable , it work correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `s` is a `std::string`, the `std::string::size()` method returns a `std::string::size_type`, which is an unsigned data type, and very often an `unsigned long` (which is 4 or 8 bytes, depending on platform).

If you subtract a positive value from an `unsigned int` containing 0, then the result will wrap to a very big positive number (ie `UINT_MAX-10`). Unsigned values are always positive, as its name suggests.

So, 0 compared < with such a wrapped number will be true.

If you assign that wrapped value to an `int` variable, the result will be negative (ie `-10`) . The compiler does an automatic integer conversion. Integer values can be negative.

That's the reason for the different results.

Comment: _unsigned long (4 bytes unsigned)_ On most modern OSs it's 8 bytes.

Comment: Thanks you very much ! now I have understood.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Note that `sizeof(long)` is 4 on Windows platforms.

Comment: @Bathsheba he wrote on **modern** :)

Comment: Underflow? No, wrap-around. Technically, there is neither underflow nor overflow with unsigned types.